# Grunt.js: htmlhint - targeting all html files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have followed the instructions on how to install it and my Gruntfile.js is now as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
require("matchdep").filterDev("grunt-*").forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    htmlhint: {
        build: {
            options: {
                'tag-pair': true,
                'tagname-lowercase': true,
                'attr-lowercase': true,
                'attr-value-double-quotes': true,
                'doctype-first': true,
                'spec-char-escape': true,
                'id-unique': true,
                'head-script-disabled': true,
                'style-disabled': true
            },
            src: ['index.html']
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerTask('default', []);
};
```

I would like to target all the .html files in my project folder which consists of different directories with htmls.

How do I target them all ?

Comment: what is your dir structure? html files are inside child dirs or can also be on root dir?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, when running grunt watch --verbose, it watches wide range of files, including the files inside node_modules... why and how to make it watch only css,scss,html,js files?

Comment: you need to edit your 'watch' task according to your project's dir structure. putting development files in 'dev' dir, and production files in 'app' for example. will make managing tasks easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wildcards in the **`src`** section.

From the htmlhint [docs](https://github.com/yaniswang/grunt-htmlhint):

```
htmlhint: {
  html1: {
    options: {
      'tag-pair': true
    },
    src: ['path/to/**/*.html']
  }
}
```

above code will target **any** .html file in **any** directory inside the specified path.

You could also specify multiple paths like so:

```
src: ['dir1/*.html', 'dir2/*.html', 'dir3/**/*.html']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
src: ['./**/*.html']
```